# How to keep the 3D view consistent between Layout and Sculpt tabs?

Tags: 3d-view

How to stop Blender refocusing the view after switching tabs?

There are some tabs at the top of the window: Layout, Modeling, Sculpting, UV Editing etc. When I'm in Layout tab and click Sculpting tab, the 3D view window viewing angle changes. This is how the default behavior looks right now:

[image: current]

I would like it to look like this - stop changing the viewing angle and stay consistent between tab changes:

[image: expected]